# HTML youtube video link not showing video but downloads file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, video, youtube

I am trying to load a video on my HTML page by using this code:

```
<video v-for="(data, key) in projectData.videos" :key="key" width="320" height="240" controls>
     <source :src="data.url">
</video>
```

An example of a source that I am using is: `http://www.youtube.com/v/qUfzflYqQeE`

The url that I am getting is from an API.

But, the issue is that when the page is loaded and the video tags are shown, it is only blank and with the source that I have pasted above it tries to download a file.

However, I don't want this to happen, I just want to load video and let it play.

If someone can please help.

Many thanks.

Comment: I guess, it will download a file, because this YouTube URL is pointing to a website: a HTML doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a `<video>` element to play a video, then the URL you give it must point to a *video* file. The URL you have does not. It leads to an HTML document.

If you want to embed YouTube videos, then use the YouTube embed code (which uses an iframe and the YouTube player along with YouTube adverts). YouTube isn't in the business of hosting plain video files for display on other sites without YouTube getting analytic data and being able to show adverts.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how I can do this. Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: Go to a YouTube video. Click Share. Click Embed. Copy/Paste.

Comment: But the thing is that the video URL that I am getting is from an API, so how can I do this? Is there another way?

Comment: Go to a YouTube video. Click Share. Click Embed. Copy/Paste. Look at the resulting code. Just replace the video id with the one you get from the API.